# error while trying to run artisan command with Artisan Facade

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-artisan, laravel-facade

here's the code

```
Route::get('run-cmd', function() {
    Artisan::call('make:controller HelloController');
});
```

and I wonder I'm getting this error...

> InvalidArgumentException in Application.php line 549:
>   Command "make:controller HelloController" is not defined.
>   Did you mean one of these?
>   make:migration
>   make:controller
>   make:middleware
>   make:request
>   make:provider
>   make:console
>   make:event
>   make:model
>   make:command

what's wrong?

Comment: Did you install all your composer dependencies? `composer install`. If so, try `composer dump-autoload`

Comment: well I think the problem must be something else , not composer dependencies, because the command "migrate" is working well , but the commands that need a parameter to be passed fail, ?

Comment: try that Artisan::call('make:controller', ['name' => 'HelloController']);

Comment: @ABDEL-RHMAN worked! , exactly what I wanted, but how about other things? maybe a  '--help' parameter? Is there a complete source for It or you just guessed the 'name' keyword?

Comment: @bobD yes, just type php artisan make:controller -h and you get needed parameters

Comment: @ABDEL-RHMAN got It, thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
Artisan::call('make:controller HelloController');
```

with

```
Artisan::call('make:controller', [ 'name' => 'HelloController' ]);
```

Comment: Some explanation why exactly this is a solution might be helpful.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/artisan#programmatically-executing-commands